# how to use fullwidth bootstrap grid system inside bootstrap modal

Tags: css, grid, bootstrap-5

i am using bootsrap 5 modal.i try to use bootstrap grig system inside the modal,but when is use grid system there are margins between modal body and grids.how can i remove these margins?any help will be highly appreciated
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `p-0` on your `.modal-body` that will set all this white padding to out.
and then add class `mx-0` on the `raw`

```css
.col-8{
  background: red;
}
.col-4{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog rounded">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--<div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>-->
      <div class="modal-body p-0">
        <div class="row mx-0">
          <div class="col-8 px-0">...</div>
          <div class="col-4 px-0">...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```